# Bind nested object to WPF data grid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that has two columns (A and B). Each column cell contains a combo box control.

I have an object that contains two list items that I want to bind to the grid view, but the binding does not work.

Binding in both DataTemplates not working correctly. UI shows the namespace instead of value.

Sample Project:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah27QQNpKj4jj2xsIsQamaOXOlin?e=jNAj2H

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel {
  public List < MainObject > MainObjects { get; set; }

  public MainWindowViewModel() {
    MainObjects = new List < MainObject > {
      new MainObject {
        AColumns = new List < ColumnA > {
          new ColumnA { Name = "A1" },
          new ColumnA { Name = "A1" }
        },
        BColumns = new List < ColumnB > {
          new ColumnB { Name = "B1" },
          new ColumnB { Name = "B1" }
        },
      }
    };
  }
}

public class MainObject {
  public List < ColumnA > ?AColumns { get; set; }
  public List < ColumnB > ?BColumns { get; set; }
}

public class ColumnA {
  public string ? Name { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestDataGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MainObjects}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Column A" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <PriorityBinding>
                                    <Binding Path="Name" Mode="TwoWay" />
                                </PriorityBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox IsEditable="True" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding AColumns}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Comment: The binding in both DataTemplate not working correctly. The display on UI showing the namespace instead of value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the "**DisplayMemberPath**" property instead of the "**Text**" property. like this

```
 <ComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding AColumns}" SelectedValuePath="Name" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```